# NodeJS event loop busy to pick up HTTP requests tasks from event queue & times out resulting in ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, http, settimeout

Because of single-threaded nature of NodeJS event loop, even before the HTTP request is triggered to downstream application, NodeJS is self timing out resulting in HTTP request not reaching to downstream application at all. i.e by the time event loop is picking up this task from the event queue timeout has already occurred (30ms have already elapsed) & the request to downstream application never got triggered.

Ideally the timer should have started after the HTTP request is triggered but in this case it seems like the timer starts immediately when the task is still in event queue waiting to be picked up by the event loop.

Meanwhile, I increased the timeout to 120ms from 30ms, the self-timeouts have reduced from ~2.5K per hour to 2-8 per hour.

```
let options = {
    url: Url, //URL to hit
    qs: params, //Query string data
    method: "GET", //Specify the method
    timeout: 30
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        return callback(new ErrorResponse(500, {error: error}));
    } else {
        return callback(null, response, body);
    }
});
```

Environment details below

- node 5.9.1
- npm 3.7.x
- request ~2.67.0
- OS Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

My understanding of event-loop & event-queue is as illustrated in the below diagram.

[image]

Can someone help me figure out what is the exact issue here.

Comment: From looking at the code of `request`, your assumption seems incorrect: the timeout timer is started when an actual connection to the server has been made ([here](https://github.com/request/request/blob/6f1b51ed43309128487739f20f9df0699a043124/request.js#L833)), not at the point where you call `request()`.

Comment: If you're getting timeouts when calling `request()`, this seems like the issue is with the server you are making a request **to**, not with the server you are making the the `request()` call **from**.  It's the remote server that is not responding quick enough.  If there's a responsiveness problem to be fixed, it's in that other server and I don't see how this has anything to do with the local event loop unless you're making thousands of requests all at once (thus overwhelming the local server's ability to process all those requests).

Comment: You need to show us your actual code (more than just one request call) and describe exactly what you observe and stop making assumptions that you know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: There is a limit to what one CPU can do.  If you are hitting that limit in this local server, then you will need to fix your code to either marshal more CPU resources onto the problem or to make your processing more efficient or to not overwhelm the one CPU by managing more carefullly what you ask it to do all at once.  We can't really advise on the best way to approach this without understanding more about the overall problem and seeing a lot more code.

Comment: A shame there is yet no accepted answer to this :-/